# automation for financial applications

Tags: automated-testing, interview

I am going to attend an interview for calypso. They have a requirement for an automation engineer, and I want to know what kind of questions are expected. They haven't told me what tools they are using for automation. Their application is a cash management, treasury and liquidity management software. Can anyone suggest what kind of questions they might ask.

Comment: applications are web based OR desktop based?

Comment: The interview is next week and i am totally tensed. They haven't told me but my guess is that it might be a web application. Can you suggest for web application? The one thing which i know is it that it is a treasury and liquidity management application and it is java based.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be too worried about application-specific questions. Unless you have prior experience in the same business (cash mgmt & co), interview questions are meant to figure out if you know your stuff.

Do you know your stuff? Then don't tense up.

Are they using the same tools you have experience with? Great, you'll have a lot to tell.
Are they using differen tools? No problem, tell them what you can do with other tools and about your general programming skills, and how you could transfer this knowledge onto their tools.

You can answer most testing/theoretical/technical inquiries with (1) what you know, (2) what you've already accomplished (and how) and (3) what you see yourself capable of in the future.
The first two are easy, and the latter should be if you're somewhat ambitious. You can always refresh some QA theory beforehand. Also don't be afraid to be honest and mention, next to your strong qualities, what you don't know (but are willing to learn).